# Reference setting value in entity symfony

Tags: symfony, doctrine, dependencies, logic, entity

I have a doubt about code organization using symfony3 and doctrine: I'll try to explain as clear as I can. Let's say I have a FootballClub entity:

```
class FootballClub
{
    // other code
    private $memberships;

    public function addMembership(Membership $membership) : FootballClub
    { 
       $this->memberships[] = $membership;
       return $this;

    }

    public function removeMembership(Membership $membership) : bool
    {
        return $this->memberships->removeElement($membership);
    }
}
```

The entity is in a many-to-one relationship with another entity, Membership, which represents the contract a player has with the club. Let's say each club
has only a limited number of membership it can acquire, number that is represented as a setting, for example, as a property in a Setting entity.
The question is: how should I reference that setting when removing a membership from the club and check that is respected? Entities should not have any dependency, so what would be the correct way to implement this? A service? can you provide an example? Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a `Settings` entity, linked in `OneToOne` relation with `FootballCluc` entity.

Define Settings like this and instanciate it in the `FootballClub`'s constructor

**Settings entity**

```
/** @Entity */
class Settings
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $maxMembership;

    // Other configurable properties ... 

    __constructor($maxMembership = 50) 
    {
        $this->maxMembership = $maxMembership;
    }

    public function getMaxMembership()
    {
        return $this->maxMembership;
    }

    public function setMaxMembership($maxMembership)
    {
        $this->maxMembership = $maxMembership;
    }
}
```

**Football Entity**

```
class FootballClub
{

    /**
     * One FootballClub has One Settings.
     * @OneToOne(targetEntity="Settings")
     * @JoinColumn(name="settings_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $settings;

    // other code
    private $memberships;

    __constructor(Settings $settings = null)
    {
        if (null === $settings) {
            $settings = new Settings();
        }
        $this->settings = $settings;
    }

    public function addMembership(Membership $membership) : FootballClub
    { 
       if ($this->settings->getMaxMembership() <= count($this->memberships)) {
           // throw new Exception("Max number of membership reached"); Strict mode
           // return false  // soft mode
       }
       $this->memberships-> = $membership;
       return $this;

    }

    public function removeMembership(Membership $membership) : bool
    {
        return $this->memberships->removeElement($membership);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In your example you set the Setting entity as an optional argument of the FootballClub constructor, but in the addMembership method of the same entity getMaxMembership() it's called unconditionally; what if $settings is null? Plus, from what I know, entities should not have any dependencies. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes my bad I was tired last night, i fix this

Comment: What do you mean by dependencies ? Do you know a case when you can create a footballclub without any settings ? If yes you can add a `setSettings` to FootballClub entity and test if the settings is defined in your addMembership method. And set the settings property `nullable`